# PHP Search box and displaying record

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, search-box

I have a search box that should look for a record that matches what was `searched(transaction_num)`
I followed the steps here [dreamweaver help](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/building-search-results-pages.html) but when I click the search button in the search page, it doesn't do anything. It doesn't jump to the results page.

Search page

```
<form action="searchRESULT.php" method="get">
  <input name="search" type="text" id="search" />
  <input name="search" type="button" id="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Result page contains the dynamic table. code generated by dreamweaver.(I use DW cs6) The filter in the recordset is set to `transaction_num = URL` parameter then 'search' which is the name of the search textfield in the search page.

Nothing happens when I click the search button. You can link me some tutorials or examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your <kbd>Search</kbd> button needs to be of the type "submit", so

```html
<input name="search" type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />
```

In PHP file

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
```

Use SQL Query like

```
$sql = 'select * from tb_name where col_name like '%".$search."%' ';
```

Comment: thanks.If what was typed in the search box doesn't match anything, how should the code go?

Comment: if search word doesn't match with data in database then it query return with 0 result..based on that you have to display message..